# Is optimizing a class for a unit test good practice, or is it premature?

Tags: unit-testing, oop, class, optimization, premature-optimization

I've seen (and searched for) a lot of questions on StackOverflow about premature optimization - word on the street is, it is the root of all evil. :P I confess that I'm often guilty of this; I don't really optimize for speed at the cost of code legibility, but I will rewrite my code in logical manners using datatypes and methods that seem more appropriate for the task (e.g. in Actionscript 3, using a typed Vector instead of an untyped Array for iteration) and if I can make my code more elegant, I will do so. This generally helps me understand my code, and I generally know why I'm making these changes.

At any rate, I was thinking today - in OOP, we promote encapsulation, attempting to hide the implementation and promote the interface, so that classes are loosely coupled. The idea is to make something that works without having to know what's going on internally - the black box idea.

As such, here's my question - is it wise to attempt to do deep optimization of code at the class level, since OOP promotes modularity? Or does this fall into the category of premature optimization? I'm thinking that, if you use a language that easily supports unit testing, you can test, benchmark, and optimize the class because it in itself is a module that takes input and generates output. But, as a single guy writing code, I don't know if it's wiser to wait until a project is fully finished to begin optimization.

For reference: I've never worked in a team before, so something that's obvious to developers who have this experience might be foreign to me.

Hope this question is appropriate for StackOverflow - I didn't find another one that directly answered my query.

Thanks!

Edit: Thinking about the question, I realize that *"profiling"* may have been the correct term instead of "unit test"; unit-testing checks that the module works as it should, while profiling checks performance. Additionally, a part of the question I should have asked before - does profiling individual modules after you've created them not reduce time profiling after the application is complete?

My question stems from the game development I'm trying to do - I have to create modules, such as a graphics engine, that *should* perform optimally (whether they will is a different story :D ). In an application where performance was less important, I probably wouldn't worry about this.

Comment: Would this be better as a CW question, since there are a few good answers and it's not really a specific topic?

Answer (score 2):

> I don't really optimize for speed at the cost of code legibility, but I will rewrite my code in logical manners using datatypes and methods that seem more appropriate for the task [...] and if I can make my code more elegant, I will do so. This generally helps me understand my code

This isn't really *optimization*, rather [*refactoring*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) for cleaner code and better design*. As such, it is a Good Thing, and it should indeed be practiced continuously, in small increments. Uncle Bob Martin (in his book [*Clean Code*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)) popularized the Boy Scout Rule, adapted to software development: *Leave the code cleaner than you found it*.

So to answer your title question rephrased, yes, refactoring code to make it unit testable is a good practice. One "extreme" of this is [*Test Driven Development*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development), where one writes the test first, then adds the code which makes the test pass. This way the code is created unit testable from the very beginning.

*Not to be nitpicky, just it is useful to clarify common terminology and make sure that we use the same terms in the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

True, optimization I believe should be left as a final task (although its good to be cognizant of where you might need to go back and optimize while writing your first draft).  That's not to say that you shouldn't re-factor things iteratively in order to maintain order and cleanliness in the code.  It is to say that if something currently serves the purpose and isn't botching a requirement of the application then the requirements should first be addressed as ultimately they are what you're responsible for delivering (unless the requirements include specifics on maximum request times or something along those lines).  I agree with Korin's methodology as well, build for function first if time permits optimize to your hearts content (or the theoretical limit, whichever comes first).

Answer (score 1):

The reason that premature optimization is a bad thing is this: it can take a lot of time and you don't know in advance where the best use of your time is likely to be.

For example, you could spend a lot of time optimizing a class, only to find that the bottleneck in your application is network latency or similar factor that is far more expensive in terms of execution time. Because at the outset you don't have a complete picture, premature optimization leads to a less than optimal use of your time. In this case, you'd probably have preferred to fix the latency issue than optimize class code.

Comment: Optimization can also complicate and obfuscate your code, making the addition or modification of features more difficult.

Comment: Well, that would be a problem with optimization generally, not the specific case of *premature* optimization.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly believe that you should **never** reduce your code readability and good design because of performance optimizations.

If you are writing code where performance is critical it may be OK to lower the style and clarity of your code, but this does not hold true for the average enterprise application. Hardware evolves quickly and gets cheaper everyday. In the end you are writing code that is going to be read by other developers, so you'd better do a good job at it!

It's always beautiful to read code that has been carefully **crafted**, where every path has a test that helps you understand how it should be used. I don't really care if it is 50 ms slower than the spaghetti alternative which does lots of crazy stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should skip optimizing for the unit test.  Optimization when required usually makes the code more complex.  Aim for simplicity.  If you optimize for the unit test you may actually de-optimize for production.

If performance is really bad in the unit test, you may need to look at your design.  Test in the application to see if performance is equally bad before optimizing.

EDIT: De-optimization is likely to occur when the data being handled varies is size.  This is most likely to occur will classes that work with sets of data.  Response may be linear, but originally slow, compared to geometric and originally fast.  If the unit test uses a small set of data, then the geometric solution may be chosen for the unit test.  When production hits the class with a large set of data performance tanks.

Sorting algorithms are a classic case for this kind of behavior and resulting de-optimizations.  Many other algorithms have similar characteristics.

EDIT2: My most successful optimization was the sort routine for a report where data was stored on disk in a memory mapped file.  The sort times were reasonable with moderate data sizes which did not require disk access.  With larger sized data sets it could take days to process the data.  Initial timings of the report showed; data selection 3 minutes, data sorting 3 days, and reporting 3 minutes.   Investigation of the sort showed that it was a fully unoptimized bubble sort (n-1 full passes for a data set of size n), roughly n square in big O notation. Changing the sorting algorithm reduced the sort time for this report to 3 minutes.  I would not have expected a unit test to cover this case, and the original code was as simple (fast) as you could get for small sets.  The replacement was much more complex and slower for very small sets, but handled large sets faster with a more linear curve, n log n in big O notation.  (Note: no optimization was attempted until we had metrics.)

In practice, I aim for a ten-fold improvement of a routine which takes at least 50% of the module run-time.  Achieving this level of optimization for a routine using 55% of the run-time will save 50% of the total run-time.

Comment: I hope this isn't a stupid question, but how could optimizing for the unit test deoptimize for production? Say you heavily optimize (maybe using some of the techniques in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort)) and you're able to cut down execution time by 50% or more. Wouldn't this translate to faster execution time in the application environment? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Ah, I see....however, it would be logical to unit-test classes in different ways, no? If a class takes multiple types of data, or data of multiple sizes, it would be logical to test for these cases. At least, that's what I'd do (but I'm kind of geeky, so I love stuff like that). I can, however, understand time constraints being an issue.

Comment: @lunchmeat317: This quickly becomes impractical for any reasonably large size of data.  I would expect unit test to use small sets (less than 10).

Comment: It took a while (a long while) to really get this. I understood what you were saying, but only after looking at big-O notation do I really understand what you mean. It's possible (and I would imagine, recommended) to unit test with different ranges of data - 10, 100, 1000, 10000, etc....but once you get past those constraints, testing becomes expensive. Good answer.